# how to use regex to split string `{{key.value}}` to two string `key` and `value`?

Tags: c#, regex

#### my question :

here is a List like :

```
var list = "{{data1.id}},{{data1.value}},{{data2.name}},{{data2.value}} ".Split(',');
```

[image]

i expect to get a `Dictionary<string,IEnumerable<string>>` data like :

```
var results = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()
{
    {"data1",new[]{"id","value"}},  
    {"data2",new[]{"name","value"}},
};
```

#### what i have tried :

```
    var regex = new Regex("{{*.*}}");
    foreach (var e in list)
    {
        var match = regex.Matches(e);
    }
```

i can use regex to get match data,but i have no idea about how to get the key `data1` and value `id`
[image]

Comment: Actually, you can split the data without regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Regex for splitting and Linq to process the result. For example,

```
var result = list.Select(x=> Regex.Match(x,@"{{(?<Key>\w+)\.(?<Value>\w+)}}"))
    .Select(m=>new {Key = m.Groups["Key"].Value,Value=m.Groups["Value"].Value})
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Key)
    .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string,IEnumerable<string>>(x.Key,x.Select(c=>c.Value)));
```

Output

[image]

Comment: this is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retrieve parts of the capture you need to use capture groups, e.g.:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"{{(\w+)\.(\w+)}}");
```

Note that I changed the regex to capture only "word" characters and you have to change `.` to `\.` since the dot character has special meaning in regular expressions (it matches any character). I further use the `@` specifier for the string to enable "verbatim mode", otherwise all the backslashes would have to be double backslashes (`\\`)

Then you can retrieve the captured values from the `Match` object returned, e.g.:

```
foreach (var e in list)
{
    var match = regex.Match(e);
    if (match.Success)
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"{match.Groups[1]} {match.Groups[2]}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No regex.  Try following :

```
            string list = "{{data1.id}},{{data1.value}},{{data2.name}},{{data2.value}} ";
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = list.Trim().Split(new char[] { '{', '}', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select((x, i) => new { val = x, index = i })
                .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.FirstOrDefault().val, y => y.LastOrDefault().val);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new Regex("{{(.*)\\.(.*)}}");
```

should match group of `.*` any characters followed by dot `\.` and then another group of any characters `.*`

Then you can get list of regex matches and group them by first group like

```
var list = "{{data1.id}},{{data1.value}},{{data2.name}},{{data2.value}} ".Split(',');
var regex = new Regex("{{(.*)\\.(.*)}}");
var matches = list.SelectMany(_ => regex.Matches(_));

var groupList = matches.Select(_ => new { data = _.Groups[1].Value, value = _.Groups[2].Value });

var groups = groupList.GroupBy(_ => _.data);

foreach (var g in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("group {0} {1}", g.Key, string.Join(",", g.Select(_ => _.value)));
```

Comment: thanks, but i get error `parsing "{{(.*\.(.*)}}" - Not enough )'s.`

Answer (score 1):

you can use bellow code

```
 var list = "{{data1.id}},{{data1.value}},{{data2.name}},{{data2.value}} ".Split(',');
        var results = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>()
        {
            {"data1",new[]{"id","value"}},
            {"data2",new[]{"name","value"}},
        };

        var regex = new Regex(@"{{(\w+)\.(\w+)}}");

        foreach (var e in list)
        {
            var match = regex.Matches(e);
            Console.WriteLine($"{match[0].Groups[1]} {match[0].Groups[2]}");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to solve your problem without `Regex`

```cs
var list = "{{data1.id}},{{data1.value}},{{data2.name}},{{data2.value}} ".Trim().Split(',');
var dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var contents = item.Trim('{', '}').Split('.');
    if (contents.Length != 2)
        continue;

    if (dict.ContainsKey(contents[0]))
    {
        var values = dict[contents[0]].ToList();
        values.Add(contents[1]);
        dict[contents[0]] = values;
    }
    else
    {
        dict.Add(contents[0], new List<string>() { contents[1] });
    }
}
```

You also have a space after last brace, make sense to call `Trim()` before parsing

Answer (score 1):

**Without Regex**

You can try below solution

1. Split your string using `','`
2. Iterate over each element and trim `{` and `}`
3. again spit by `.`, to get data and value

   ```
   //Step - 1
   var list = "{{data1.id}},{{data1.value}},{{data2.name}},{{data2.value}}".Split(',');

   foreach(var element in list)
   { 
       //Step 2
       var input = element.Trim('{', '}').Split('.');
       //Step 3
       Console.WriteLine($"Data: {input[0]}, Value {input[1]}");
       //You can perform dictionary operations here
   }
   ```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/onbNrc)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var list = "{{data1.id}},{{data1.value}},{{data2.name}},{{data2.value}}"
            .Split(',')
            .Select(x => x.Trim(new char[] { '{', '}' }));
var groupBy = list.Select(x => x.Split('.'))
                  .GroupBy(x => x[0])
                  .ToDictionary(y=> y.Key, y.Key[0] );
```